# Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.liferay.util.dao.orm; version="[6.2.0,7.0.0)"

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I created a service builder and in the *-service I need com.liferay.util.dao.orm.CustomSQLUtil in order to execute custom sql. I created *FinderImpl and created a method in which I used CustomSQLUtil. I built and deployed the *-api and *-service successfully. But when I dragged and dropped the *-api and *-service onto the running server, the above mentioned error comes out. 
My bnd.bnd file is as follows:-

```
Bundle-SymbolicName: customuser-service
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Liferay-Require-SchemaVersion: 1.0.0
Liferay-Service: true
Bundle-ClassPath:\
   .,\
   lib/util-java.jar,\
```

And build.gradle is as follows:-

```
dependencies {
    compile group: "biz.aQute.bnd", name: "biz.aQute.bndlib", version: "3.1.0"
    compile group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.osgi.util", version: "3.0.0"
    compile group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.portal.spring.extender", version: "2.0.0"
    compile group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "com.liferay.portal.kernel", version: "2.6.0"
    compile project(":modules:customuser:customuser-api")

    compile group: 'com.liferay.portal', name: 'portal-kernel', version: '5.2.3'

    compile group: 'com.liferay.portal', name: 'util-java', version: '6.2.4'

}

buildService {
    apiDir = "../customuser-api/src/main/java"
    osgiModule = true
    propsUtil = "com.example.service.util.PropsUtil"
}
```

Please help... thanx in advance..

Comment: Can you update your question with the full content of the bnd file and the content of generated MANIFEST.MF file?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line

```
provided group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.custom.sql", version: "1.0.0"
```

to your build.gradle dependencies. E.g.:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: "biz.aQute.bnd", name: "biz.aQute.bndlib", version: "3.1.0"
    compile group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.osgi.util", version: "3.0.0"
    compile group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.portal.spring.extender", version: "2.0.0"
    compile group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "com.liferay.portal.kernel", version: "2.6.0"
    compile project(":modules:customuser:customuser-api")
    compile group: 'com.liferay.portal', name: 'portal-kernel', version: '5.2.3'
    compile group: 'com.liferay.portal', name: 'util-java', version: '6.2.4'

    provided group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.custom.sql", version: "1.0.0"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need that import, it won't resolve ever.

Use "com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.custom.sql.CustomSQLUtil" instead from gradle dep: "com.liferay:com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.custom.sql:1.0.0".